# How do I use custom view (.xib) as navigation bar in UITableViewController and UIViewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xib

I created a custom View (`CustomNav.xib` file) that I want to be the navigation of all my `UITableViewControllers` and `UIViewControllers`. I have tried setting the Class of a View to `CustomNav` but it wont appear among the options. (`XCode`, `Swift2`)